# Improve regex that works

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm not a regex expert, so please be nice  :-)

I created this regex to verify if a user submitted a day of the week (in italian language):

```
/((lun|mart|giov)e|mercol(e?)|vener)d(ì|i('?)|í)|sabato|domenica/
```

This regex **perfectly works** and it matches the following:

- lun**ed**i
- lun**ed**ì
- lun**ed**í
- lun**ed**i’
- mart**ed**i
- mart**ed**ì
- mart**ed**í
- mart**ed**i'
- mercol**ed**i
- mercol**ed**ì
- mercol**ed**í
- mercol**ed**i'
- mercoldi
- mercoldì
- mercoldí
- mercoldi'
- giov**ed**i
- giov**ed**ì
- giov**ed**í
- giov**ed**i'
- ven**erd**i
- ven**erd**ì
- ven**erd**í
- ven**erd**i'
- sabato
- domenica

Now consider the first part of the `regex` and focus on `venerdì`: as you can see, I added an `OR` (`|`) just to manage the `venerdì` day, just because of the presence of that “r”.

Anything works just fine but I’m here to ask if is there any way to start the regex this way:

```
(lun|mar|giov|ven)e
```

and then manage that “r” some way.

I red about `backrefences` and `conditionals` but I’m not sure they can be of any help.

My idea is something like: “if the first group captured ‘ven’, than add “r” to the “e” right after the end of the group.

Is this possible?

Comment: _How_ do you want to "improve" the regex? Make it shorter by all means? Faster to evaluate? More readable?

Comment: Or how about accepting only the standard normalized version and not every version some ppl tought about? A search yielded only luned**ì**, not luned**ìíi(i')**. That makes your regex faster, easier and more readable!

Comment: @tobias_k: you're right, I wanted to say _shorter_

Comment: @Chrᴉz: mmm, problem with the user is she can write it any way and the server must "understand" it. I could use Levenshtein too, but in this case I prefer the regex

Comment: @3000 why do you want to make it shorter ? Said else-way; what do you want to solve by making it shorter ?

Comment: @Tensibai: really not "solving" anything (as I said my regex works fine), it was just my own curiosity, sort of "can this be even more compact?"

Comment: As you say: you're validating use input... how about not relying on the user typing in a valid day, but instead provide them with either a date picker, or a simple drop-down menu?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: it's a particular case where a user can type whatever he wants (just like a traditional search engine)

Comment: @3000 Still, if it's a search function of sorts, surely why are you running the input through some very specific regex? Either use some specific software for fuzzy matching, or enforce a stricter input policy.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: have you ever noticed how behaves Google when it shows you a rich, dedicated UI when you search for weather or football data?   :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't "golf" your regex. If you want to improve it at all, make it more readable. While it it certainly worthwile to use different cases for the different "i" variants, everything else should IMHO be kept as simple as possible.

How about something like this?

```
(lune|marte|mercole?|giove|vener)d(ì|i'?|í)|sabato|domenica
```

Don't use backreferences and other advanced features if you don't need them, just to make your regex a few chars shorter. Even if *you* would still understand what it means, think about your fellow co-developers -- or just yourself two months from now.

I just removed a few redundant `(...)` and the "shared e" part. Note how (besides the `(...)`) it is the same length, whether you use `(lun|mart|giov)e` or `lune|marte|giove`, but the latter is arguably more readable. Similarly, a backreference or some conditional would likely make your regex *longer* instead  of shorter -- and *considerably* more complicated.

Comment: This is exactly one of my first tries, then a sort of inner _bad devil of dry programming_ convinced me to consider all these common "e"   ;-)

Comment: @3000 While from the performance point of view no alternative should match at the same location in string (`|marte|mercole?` => `|m(?:arte|ercole?)`), the majority of users will still prefer readability to efficiency with such short static patterns.